# how to convert exponent** to Math.pow javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, parsing

can some solve this problem? I am trying to convert exponent '**' to Math.pow. How do I do this in JavaScript or jQuery?

this

```
((20000 * ((5.5/100)/12)) / (1 - ((1 + ((5.5/100)/12))**(-1 * 120))))
```

to this

```
((20000 * ((5.5/100)/12)) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + ((5.5/100)/12),-1 * 120)))
```

this code what I did but failed.

```
   function detectAndFixTrivialPow( expressionString ) {

    var pattern = /(\w+)\*\*(\w+)/i;

    var fixed = expressionString.replace( pattern, 'Math.pow($1,$2)' );
    return fixed;
}

eval( detectAndFixTrivialPow( " ((20000 * ((5.5/100)/12)) / (1 - ((1 + ((5.5/100)/12))**(-1 * 120))))" ) );
```

Thank you who can solve this problem.

Comment: You mean you need to parse the expression as a string and rewrite it?

Comment: You'll need to write an expression parser, or find a parser library for JS.

Comment: jQuery is useless for this. It's mainly for accessing the DOM, and has a few utility functions for arrays and objects. But it has nothing for string processing.

Comment: @Barmar I update my code

Comment: `\w+` won't match parentheses. You can't use a JavaScript regular expression to match a balanced parenthesized expression.

Comment: Would the input have function calls, like `Math.sqrt` or `Math.max`? Can the input have string literals, like `"abc".indexOf("b") * 3`? Can the input have logical operators like `!` Can the input have `++` or `--` operators? Can the input have bracket member access, like `[1, 2][1]`? Etc, etc... The more complex it becomes, the more you will *need* to use a parser library. Please update the question to include the boundaries of what can occur in the input.